# "No overload matches this call" - in mapStateToProps method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, state, store

I treat the question as a mental therapy. My problem:

[image]

and the whole error message:

[image]

The issue occurs when I want (and need) to add new field in the `StateProps`, the root of the issue is `projectList` variable in the code (the whole component):

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { UsedInProjectsPure, OwnProps, DispatchProps, StateProps } from './UsedInProjectsPure';
import {
  AppStore,
  selectComponent,
  fetchProjectDetailsAction,
  selectProjectDetails,
  fetchProjectListAction,
} from '../../../../store';

export const mapStateToProps = (store: AppStore) => ({
  component: selectComponent(store),
  projectsList: selectProjectDetails(store),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchProjectDetails: fetchProjectDetailsAction.request,
  fetchProjectList: fetchProjectListAction.request,
};

 export const UsedInProjects = connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps, AppStore>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(UsedInProjectsPure);

export type UsedInProjectsProps = OwnProps;
```

Interface of store:

```
export const selectedProject = (store: AppStore) => 
   store.projects.selectedProject;

export const isProjectListInProgress = (store: AppStore) => 
   store.projects.projectListInProgress;
export const selectProjectList = (store: AppStore) => 
   store.projects.projectList;
export const selectProjectListError = (store: AppStore) => 
   store.projects.projectListError;

export const isProjectDetailsInProgress = (store: AppStore) =>
   store.projects.projectDetailsInProgress;
export const selectProjectDetails = (store: AppStore) => 
   store.projects.projectDetails;
export const selectProjectDetailsError = (store: AppStore) => 
   store.projects.projectDetailsError;
```

Anyone is able to give even direction what is wrong? Where I need to improve types?